# Standby current consumption stm32g030f6p6

Tags: stm32

At first I designed a simple STM board with an NTC that when the temperature goes high it start drawing 20 mA current instead of 30 µA (that consumes in standby mode) and the main panel understand that and start to alarm.

The whole idea of working algorithm is that STM goes into standby mode and wakes up by the internal RTC every 4 seconds and checks the temperture. If everything is fine it goes to standby mode, otherwise it starts to consume power and provoke an alarm.

Now I'm facing some problems.

1. Even with the same values for RTC and connecting all my detectors at the same time, after some time the start to blink timely different ant that's weird
2. Even with the same code some boards go into standby mode and current goes below 100 µA but some don't, I'm considering ICs quality but don't think that's the case and weirder is that tomorrow when I check them all work fine but after like one hour weird behavior starts again and some of them consume power more than 2mA in standby mode :)
3. We all know that reset pin needs 10 kΩ or more resistor for pull up but this board than I'm working and debugging with STLINK V2 needs reset pin directly connected to +3.3V otherwise doesn't download the code on micro and that's weird,
4. BOOT0 pin is floating in my board, can it be the problem why some boards work fine and some don't or you think the quality of STM32 ICs are different that some work fine and some don't.

I leave some pictures of schematic and my code:

[image: schematics]

```c
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
uint32_t AD_RES = 0, NTC = 0;
long int x;
_Bool fire_mode = 0;
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
 ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

RTC_HandleTypeDef hrtc;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_RTC_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    // Read & Update The ADC Result
    AD_RES = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    
}

  void stm32l_lowPowerSetup(){
    // Configure RTC to wake up after 500ms 
//_stm32l_disableGpios(); // Disable GPIOs based on configuration
//HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&hrtc, 4096, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV16);

__HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE(); // Enable Power Control clock

// Disable Unused Gpios

// GPIO Wake up is configured by CubeMx config and keeping the GPIO activated


// Switch to STOPMode
HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();
  }

void stm32l_lowPowerResume(){
  // Reinit clocks
SystemClock_Config();
// Deactivate RTC wakeUp
HAL_RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer(&hrtc);
// Reinit GPIOs
MX_GPIO_Init();

}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  
  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  
  
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
  
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(45);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  NTC = (68 * AD_RES) / (4096 - AD_RES);
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    if(NTC < 57)
    {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      fire_mode = 1;
    }else if(fire_mode == 0)
    {
      HAL_Delay(1);
      stm32l_lowPowerSetup();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDiv = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc1.Init.SamplingTimeCommon1 = ADC_SAMPLETIME_12CYCLES_5;
  hadc1.Init.SamplingTimeCommon2 = ADC_SAMPLETIME_12CYCLES_5;
  hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.TriggerFrequencyMode = ADC_TRIGGER_FREQ_HIGH;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_COMMON_1;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief RTC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */

  /** Initialize RTC Only
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPullUp = RTC_OUTPUT_PULLUP_NONE;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Enable the WakeUp
  */
  if (HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&hrtc, 8080, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB7 PB8 PB9 PB1
                           PB2 PB3 PB4 PB5
                           PB6 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_1
                          |GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5
                          |GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC14 PC15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA0 PA2 PA3 PA4
                           PA5 PA8 PA11 PA12
                           PA15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4
                          |GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_12
                          |GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA1 PA6 PA7 PA11*/
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_11;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

I expect knowing the reason why some boards work and some don't and is there a problem with my code or board or what is it:)

Comment: Most of your questions are related to hardware design and has nothing to do with programming. Stackoverflow is for programming related topic, it will be better for you to post it at [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com), but before you do that, please read the [Getting started with STM32G0 Series hardware development](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00443870-getting-started-with-stm32g0-series-hardware-development-stmicroelectronics.pdf) which should answered some of your question about Boot0 pin and Reset pin pull-up.

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of the PA1 (load_active), it basically connect the 180 ohm resistor between 3.3V and GND for no obvious reason and consumed (3.3-0.6)/180 = 15mA when active.

Comment: the reason is that main panel understand something is wrong with this power consumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Quantify. I don't use Cube/HAL so don't understand how do you set up RTC, but it appears to me that you use LSI (you don't have any crystal). LSI frequency dispersion in 'G0 is around 3% at room temperature. Additionally, wakeup from Standby, the default HSI clock frequency etc. all have some dispersion.
2. That may stem from multiple sources so that's up to you to investigate. Make sure you have STLink disconnected while measuring low-power currents. However, the pulldowns for transistors might've not be needed at the first place, as the 'G0 has a pullups/pulldowns configurable for Standby using PWR_PDCRx registers, see *Standby mode* subchapter of PWR chapter in RM.
3. That is definitively wrong. NRST has an internal nominally 40kOhm pullup and does not need an external pullup, see *NRST input characteristics* chapter in datasheet. Direct connection to VDD is also completely wrong. You should have NRST connected to NRST output of STLink and have the Hardware Reset option selected in programmer/debugger, as if firmware is running and going into Shutdown that does prevent debugger/programmer from working.
4. BOOT0 is not used as long as you don't change nBOOT_SEL option bit from its default.

Comment: This is not an answer, and should be posted as comment.